# IIS FTP Upload, file rights

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, ftp

We needed a way to allow administrators to upload support files to user directories using FTP with IIS. We have folder redirection and roaming profiles in place and we have created an active directory user called FTP1. 
This user has rights to access the user profile directories on the network share, in order to upload files to the users directory for support etc. We have created an FTP site in IIS and allowed the FTP1 user to access this site.

Uploading to user profile directories now works fine, but unfortunately there is a problem with the file security attributes. The file cannot be seen and accessed by the users who own the profile directory, because the default security attributes only allow access by FTP1 and the administrator.

How can I achieve that uploaded files via FTP are automatically accessible for read-write access for the normal user who owns the user profile directory?

I have tried setting the file rights to 777 (linux style), but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about your folder structure and how you normally do permissions, I'm going to take a shot and say disabling inheritance on the permissions a few folders into the structure and then explicitly naming permissions and inheritance further down would be a decent bet.

Then again, that depends on how you have your users directed to the folders when logging in to FTP.  For example, if you're using DFS to create the virtual folders, then the permissions would have to be checked on both sides.  There's not really enough info on your structure to give you an idea of where your hangup might be.